React-Leaflet how to make circle change size relative to zoom
In React-Leaflet I put a L.circleMarker in some coordinate and and gave it some radius. when I zoom in the radius size shrinks, but I want it to grow bigger. for example if I drew a circle around New-York I would want it to stay around New-York when I zoom in, meaning the circle would have to grow bigger as I zoom but maintain it bounds relative to the map . I would also want the circle to follow my cursor and so I cant use a polyline with an array of fixed coordinates

turns out i needed to use L.circle, hope it helps
